# How to design this test plan in JMeter

Tags: jmeter

My setup is as follow, so the `SET UP` thread group help me to create some prerequisite data and I have two action item

1. After that my `thread group` will run. (for example 6 user for 30 min)
2. Once the above thread group finish the second thread group will trigger (for my case I have configured it in tear down thread group01).

At last I have the `tear down thread group02` to clean up the data which I created in first set up thread group (this has a simple clean up script).

Problem Statement: `Tear down thread group02` trigger before `Tear down thread group01` as
`Tear down thread group01` configured as the `thread group` like `6User with 30 min duration.`

How to solve this, like first `set up thread group` should execute then `thread group` with user and duration then `Tear down thread group01` (may be I can use some other thread group which I dont have clue at current) then `Tear down thread group02`

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to run your Thread Groups upside down one by one just tick `Run Thread Groups consecutively (i.e. one at a time)` box on [Test Plan](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Test_Plan) level:

[image]

in this case the Thread Groups will be executed in the order they appear in the [Test Plan](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Test_Plan)

If in future you will need to run more than one Thread Group at a time you can still control the execution order on Samplers level using for example [Inter-Thread Communication Plugin](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/top-ten-jmeter-plugins#comm) and [If Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#If_Controller)